# Low latency collection for edits

Tags: java, collections

Here is the situation  - I need to maintain a collection(unbounded/single writer) of ids(string) in Java 7.
As new records come in with a particular flag set (immaterial)- I attempt to insert.
If I find a pre-existing record in the collection - I alert and over-write anyways.
If new records come in with the flag unset - I attempt to remove the record,if one exists.
All lookups(2-step) to be avoided for performance.
Insert/update/remove to be as close to O(1) as possible.

Would HashSet be the most apt collection for this?

Comment: How is the collection read from? Is it accessed by multiple threads concurrently?

Comment: No reads required - but may allow for future if no additional cost

Comment: A HashSet is perfect for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is single-threaded, `HashSet` should be a good match. Sample implementation:

```
Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();

void processRecord(Record record) {
    if (record.hasFlag()) {
        if (!ids.add(record.getId())) {
            alertDuplicate(record);
        }
    } else {
        ids.remove(record.getId());
    }
}
```